# Backup websites with database in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, backup, database

I am having one ubuntu local server in which we used to have all our development websites. They all are php based sites. I would like to know whether we can have script or something to cron backup the files and database daily to external harddisc ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little script I wrote to backup my apache-configs, webfiles & db to Amazon S3.
The sole purpose of the server is a web server where every developer uses his own homedir. So, There is a file in `/home' with a list of users that need to be backed up.

```
#!/bin/bash
#    2012 Bart De Vos
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA


# location of this script
DIRECTORY=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)
INSTALLER_FILENAME=`basename $0`

# error handling
function error_exit
{
    echo "Error on line ${1:-'Aborting script.'}" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

function backup
{
    # exit on errors
    set -e

    # getting hostname
    HOSTNAME_FQDN=`hostname --fqdn` || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error determening hostname"

    echo "Determening timestamp"
    timestampbackup=`/bin/date +%Y%m%d%H` || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error determening timestamp"

    echo "Create backupdir"
    /bin/mkdir /backup/${timestampbackup} || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error creating backupdir"

    echo "Dump and save MYSQL for all dbs"
    /usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases --opt -c -e -Q -uScriptRunner -pMySuperSecretPasswordThaIAlmostForgotToRemoveFromTheScript | /bin/gzip > /backup/${timestampbackup}/sqlbackup.sql.gz || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error backing up mysql"

    echo "Itterate users in /home/.backup"
    for username in `awk -F: '{print $1}' /home/.backup`
    do
        echo "Backing up user: $username"
        /bin/tar -czpf /backup/${timestampbackup}/${username}.tar.gz /home/${username} || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error backing up $username"
    done    

    echo "Get configs"
    /bin/tar -czpf /backup/${timestampbackup}/httpdconfigs.tar.gz /etc/httpd/conf.d/ || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error backing up httpd conf.d"


    echo "Copy to S3 bucket"
    /usr/bin/s3cmd --config=/backup/.s3cfg put /backup/ s3://${HOSTNAME_FQDN} --recursive || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error with transfer to S3"

    echo "Remove backupdir"
    /bin/rm /backup/${timestampbackup} -rf || error_exit "${LINENO}: Error deleting backupdir"

    echo "All done!"

}

backup
```

Before you can use it, you need to install s3cmd and create a `.config` file with your S3 security credentials. (Will create this upon first use).

Don't forget to check/alter paths because they can differ between distro's/versions.

Comment: Thanks for the code.
Can I have another remote server instead of Amazon S3 ?
or, can I use dropbox ?

Comment: Sure, just change the s3cmd code with scp and you can push it to another server. DropBox is not really a professional backup solution imo...